# How to return latitude and longitude of a point in a feature layer for Esri Javascript API 4.18

Tags: javascript, esri, arcgis-js-api

I've created a client-side feature (point) and would like to know how to return it's lat and long. I've tried using the queryFeatures method, but have not been able to return anything.

```
featureLayer
.queryFeatures({
  returnGeometry: true,
})
.then(function (results) {
  // do something with the resulting graphics
  console.log(results.features.geometry.latitude);
});
```

EDIT: I'm only adding one point that I need to query. It has an initial location, but is moved when the user clicks a new location on the map.

```
var features = [
  {
    geometry: {
      type: "point",
      x: -94.68,
      y: 46.72,
    },
    attributes: {
      ObjectID: 1,
    },
  },
];

var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
  source: features, // autocast as a Collection of new Graphic()
  objectIdField: "ObjectID",
});

map.add(featureLayer);
```

Comment: Is the only point?, if not, can you identify somehow the point you want to query? .. I am guessing that you problem is to query the point in the feature layer, is that it?

Comment: Yes, it's only one point. I've added some details to the post about how it's created and how it's moved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query a feature layer that has the features on client side, you need to use the `FeatureLayerView` methods ([ArcGIS API - FeatureLayerView queryFeatures](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-layers-FeatureLayerView.html#queryFeatures)). This methods act on every graphic available to dray on the view, these is what you are looking for.

The query methods of `FeatureLayer` act on the service, that is not your case.

BTW, if you only need to update the geometry just use `applyEdits` method of the feature layer ([ArcGIS API - FeatureLayer applyEdits](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#applyEdits)).